# How to use Network Mecanim Animator of the Fusion

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new in Photon Fusion.
I added Network Mecanim Animator to the model.
when play the app the animation of the hosted user was synchronized to the client.
but the animation of the client doesn't synchronized to the hosted user.
How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you fix the issue ? I have the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/manual/prebuilt-components#networkmecanimanimator),

> `NetworkMecanimAnimator` will only sync the `Animator` component from the State Authority to Proxies.

Since the hosted user has State Authority, it will synchronize its `Animator` parameters (eg. int, float, bool, trigger) to all the clients, so the clients animations will be synced.

Similar to networked properties, they can only be changed by the State Authority. Any change by the clients will not be synchronized back to the host or other clients.

It helps to keep in mind that everything that the client sees, including animations, are just visuals reflecting a networked state. The networked state can only be affected and changed by the State Authority. The clients can only affect the networked state via inputs or RPCs. According to the [documentation](https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/tutorials/host-mode-basics/6-remote-procedure-calls) it is best to use networked state unless they are [one-time actions](https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/manual/rpc).

Here are some useful documentation and references from Photon on how to implement animations in Fusion

- https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/manual/prebuilt-components#networkmecanimanimator
- https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/manual/animation
- https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/technical-samples/fusion-animations